# "UET is engineering a stronger Pakistan", is it correct to say so?

Tags: verbs, nouns, present-participles

For a local festival, my university - UET - has written a sentence on the entering gate, that reads as "UET is engineering a stronger Pakistan"

According to my knowledge, engine is a verb, and engineer is a noun as `an engineer is a person who engines.` So, can `engineer` be regarded as a verb and `engineering` is the present participle of it? And if so is the case, is it formal or informal?

Comment: Completely formal. Wikipedia: Engineering - is the application of scientific, economic, social, and practical knowledge in order to design, build, maintain, and improve structures - define engineering: 
1. 
the branch of science and technology concerned with the design, building, and use of engines, machines, and structures.
2.
the action of working artfully to bring something about.
"if not for his shrewd engineering, the election would have been lost"

Comment: [engineer](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/engineer?q=engineer) is also a verb. Whether you can engineer a country is another matter

Comment: There is a documentary called Engineering an Empire

Comment: I would be very interested in a source for _engine_ as a verb.

Comment: And I would be very much interested if that source marks it formal to use `engine` as a verb.

Comment: Engine is not a verb.  Engineer is.

Comment: @ArslanAli: I had hoped _you_ could provide such a source, since you are the first person ever I have seen claiming that _engine_ is a verb :)

Comment: @ArslanAli They are referring to your "a person who *engines*" - you have used "engine" as a verb here :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of senses in which "[engineer](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/engineer)" is a verb, and they don't all depend on the subject actually being an engineer, although the concepts are related:

> - to lay out, construct, or manage as an engineer: *engineer a bridge*
> - to contrive or plan out usually with more or less subtle skill and craft: *engineer a business deal*
> - to guide the course of: *engineer a rally*
> - to modify or produce by genetic engineering: *corn engineered to resist crop pests*

The sense in your sentence is "to plan out" and/or "to guide the course of". Just as an engineer makes plans and constructs something, so too does UET - just they are not constructing a building.

Actually, UET could be seen as (or see themselves as!) a [social engineer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_engineering_%28political_science%29):

> Social engineering is a discipline in social science that refers to
>   efforts to influence popular attitudes and social behaviors on a large
>   scale, whether by governments, media, or private groups.
>
> A social engineer is one who tries to influence popular attitudes,
>   social behaviors, and resource management on a large scale.

Really they are just claiming that they have the skill and expertise to make their graduates - and therefore Pakistan - strong.

Answer (score 1):

Engine is a noun, not a verb, as far as I know. Engineering can also be a noun, but here it is used as a verb in the present continuous tense. It is correct and formal.

Perhaps the intention was to create a strapline, i.e. without the "is"

**UET, Engineering A Stronger Pakistan**